# symfony security prod doesn't work

Tags: security, symfony, production-environment

I'm using symfony 3.2.3, and I want restrict access on same pages.
Ok, no problem! Configuring security.yml, all can be done, and actually it works in dev environment.
But, when I switch my symfony site in production mode, nothing works any more!

Switching to prod commands:

- php bin\console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

I have 4 pages:

- /homepage (can access everyone)
- /lucky (can access everyone)
- /auth_area (can access only logged users)
- /backend (can access only ROLE_ADMIN users)

Here my security.yml

security:

```
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER_LOGGED: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER_LOGGED

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/auth_area, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Finally, all works fine on dev, nothing works in prod: anonymous user can access everywhere! ;(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your access control these lines are useless if you have only 2 specific areas with limited access: `- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` and - `{ path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`. Comment out these 2 directives, delete the cache and try. PS: I think the first directive is always matched and cause your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As written by [gp_sflover in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328672/symfony-security-prod-doesnt-work#comment71810796_42328672):

> PS: I think the first directive is always matched and cause your problem.

and in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html):

> For each incoming request, Symfony checks each `access_control` entry to find one that matches the current request. As soon as it finds a matching `access_control` entry, it stops - only the **first** matching `access_control` is used to enforce access.

So you have to change the order of your rules and put the rule that match every request (`path: ^/`) at the end:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/auth_area, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Is `^/login$` needed? It would seem to be covered under `^/` and the other two do not apply.

Comment: @JaredFarrish in the case described in your question you need only the directives that prevents the access, because the users are already allowed to access any page of your site as `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` (this happens because each  firewall is enabled `security: true` by default).

Comment: To wit: I'm not the OP.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, you're right. It's not required but it's part of the [default configuration of FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-4-configure-your-application-s-security-yml). So it may be better to keep it, for example if later you change the roles of `path: ^/` you may have unexpected behaviours.

Comment: Hi @mardif if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.